# Не работает наследование объектов в unity

Tags: unity3d

Не могу понять, что с наследованием объектов в  Unity, вроде бы раньше все двигалось взаимосвязанно (вместе с кубом двигалась и капсула), а теперь они перемещаются только при прямом взаимодействии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У обоих объектов был атрибут  Rigidbody, а должен быть только у родителя (для совместных движений связанных объектов).